# UIViewController+xib 's view return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIViewController which instantiated with XIB. In iOS7, there was no problem; however in iOS6 the view controller's view returned nil.

Most strange thing here is, this symptom go away if I copy this .h .m .xib to a new project. Is there any suggestion to track this?

I tried to remove all the code in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and initWith.. methods. There's no single line of code implementing when the view controller is instantiated.

After initWithNibName invoked, The viewDidLoad, viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews are never invoked.

**Added**
Even I removed xib and remove all the properties and methods from .h and .m, I still have this problem. What's wrong????

Comment: Did you override `loadView` and forget to call `super` ?

Comment: Nope. I didn't override loadview.

Comment: Did you tried to bind a new/different XIB file with the same .h, .m file ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless actually I removed the XIB and tried with init method instead of initWithNib, but there's the same problem.

Comment: Is this on the Simulator or a device?

Comment: It's simulator. I don't have any iOS6 device...